# Is there any Intelij plugin for Team Foundation Server (TFS) windows that I can but it in CI\CD and run the project?

Tags: java, windows, intellij-idea, kotlin, tfs

Is there any Intellij plugin for Team Foundation Server (TFS) windows that I can but it in CI\CD and run the project? I have a project with jar files and kotlin and I want to know if their is a plugin that can run my project? (in TFS)

Comment: Check this TFS plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs

Comment: I see that it's not working in the last tfs version

Answer (score 1):

There is **Azure DevOps Services Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA** which can be installed from IntelliJ by browsing the [Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops).

1. In IntelliJ, open plugin settings:

   - Linux: from the `File` menu,
           select `Settings...` then `Plugins`
   - Mac: from the I`ntelliJ IDEA menu`,
        select `Preferences...` then `Plugins`
   - Windows: from the `File` menu,
        select `Settings...` then `Plugins`
2. Click the `Browse repositories...` button and search for "Visual
   Studio Team Services".
3. Click the `Install plugin` button and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

The Azure Repos Plugin for IntelliJ allows you to connect to your Git repositories on Azure DevOps Services and Team Foundation Server (TFS) in a seamless and intuitive way. You can also use this plugin to import projects into Azure Repos or create pull requests in your Azure DevOps Services/TFS Git repository.

*This plugin enable working with Git and TFVC repositories on Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015+.*

More details about how to use it, please kindly refer our official guide here--[Azure Repos Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/create-repo-intellij?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fjava%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Frepos%2Fgit%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops)

[image: *]

Comment: I am using inteliij 2019.2 and can't find "Visual Studio Team Services" in plugin. Do you know how to connect for 2019.2 community edition?

Comment: @SachinSharma We now renamed Visual Studio Team Services to **Azure DevOps Service**. Sorry some old tutorial haven't changed especially for some 3rd-party extension, sorry for any inconvenience. Please search **Azure DevOps** in plugin marketplace. Also add a update screenshot, kindly review it.

Comment: I've used git extension to coonect to azure devops and it is working but normal process of using ```Azure DevOps git or TFVC``` didn't work which is weird. I am not sure if I can share all the screenshots here but in ```2019.2``` they've made it little weird

Comment: @SachinSharma That sounds weird. It should work properly. Make sure you have meet all prerequisites first. For TFVC version control. You must have the TF command line tool installed to be able to use TFVC features. Please go through this official link --[TFVC set up Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/intellij-faq?view=azure-devops#tfvc-setup-requirements). It's not able to share screenshot in comment with SO. Since it's a different question, if you still get issue, suggest you file a new case. This will also be easy to track.

Answer (score 0):

There is one by Microsoft. See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops